# Array to more than one string

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have a JavaScript array:

```
cities = ["LA", "NYC", "Riyadh", "Frankfurt"]
```

The `cities.toString()` function will give me

```
"LA, NYC, Riyadh, Frankfurt"
```

How do I get

```
"LA", "NYC", "Riyadh", "Frankfurt"
```

Comment: In which data type would you store more than one string?

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way I can think of is to use `JSON.stringify` and drop the first and last characters with `slice`, like this

```
var cities = ["LA", "NYC", "Riyadh", "Frankfurt"]
console.log(JSON.stringify(cities).slice(1, -1));
// "LA","NYC","Riyadh","Frankfurt"
```

If you want it, exactly like you mentioned in your answer, use `map` function to generate new Strings surrounded by double quotes and finally join them with `,` like this

```
console.log(cities.map(function (currentCity) {
    return '"' + currentCity + '"';
}).join(', '));
// "LA", "NYC", "Riyadh", "Frankfurt"
```

If your actual strings will not have any `,` in them, then you can chain the `split` and `join` calls, like this

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(cities).slice(1, -1).split(",").join(", "));
// "LA", "NYC", "Riyadh", "Frankfurt"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) function of array to join the array elements using any separator like:

```
var result = '"' + cities.join('", "') + '"' ;
```

Check the working [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/doucj1gb/1/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change an array into a string, there's [`array.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join). It works well with whatever delimiter you want to use:

```
var array = ["LA", "NYC", "Riyadh", "Frankfurt"];
var string = '"' + array.join('", "') + '"';
// Result: "LA", "NYC", "Riyadh", "Frankfurt"
```